# Query for ANY value in complex key (AKA wildcard)

Tags: couchdb

I went through docs and SO questions but didn't find any clear answer for my particular case.

Having this complex (emitting array) key map func in view

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.userFirstName && doc.userLastName && doc.userGender && doc.homeCountry && doc.homeCity) {
      emit([
        doc.userFirstName,
        doc.userMiddleName,
        doc.userLastName,            
      ], null)
    }
```

I want to query it with values some of which are empty - so query could accept *ANY* values from the key, i.e.

```
userFirstName = *anyvalue*
userMiddleName = *anyvalue*
userLastName = "Mozart"
```

If it's possible - what should my startKey= and endKey= request parameters look like?
I tried

```
startkey=[{},{},"Mozart"]&endkey=[{},{},"Mozart"]
```

but with no avail - got no rows..

Comment: This is not possible with a single index. You can only do sub-key searches for the first part of the key.

Comment: What do you mean by the "first part of the key"? That (using presented map fuction) firstName and middleName should exist in the query when we are searching for lastName?

Comment: I'm not sure how "first part of the key" is confusing. The key you're emitting is `[doc.userFirstName, doc.userMiddleName, doc.userLastName]`. The "first part" would be any part that comes before the other parts. So the first name, or the first part of the first name, for instance. As an example, given the name "John B Smith", the key might be `["John","B","Smith"]`, and you could then search for `["J"]`, or `["John",B"]` or `["John","B","S"]`, but not `[{},"B",{}]` or `[{},{},"Smith"]`

Comment: Thank you, so I got it right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Any_value" wildcard in couchdb query isn't possible (yet, question to devs - why not?), so the only way to perform multy-dimensional lookup with empty (=accept_any) values is to maintain indexes for all possible combinations of non-empty search values. I ended up with this _design doc:

```
let ddoc = {
      '_id': '_design/search',
      'views': {
        'firstOnly': {'map': firstOnly},
        'middleOnly': {'map': middleOnly},
        'lastOnly': {'map': lastOnly},
        'firstLast': {'map': firstLast},
        'firstMiddle': {'map': firstMiddle},
        'middleLast': {'map': middleLast}
      }
    };
```

where (i.e. for known middleName and lastName) map function looks like:

```
const middleLast =
  `function(doc) {
    if (doc.userMiddleName && doc.userLastName) {
      emit([
        doc.userMiddleName,
        doc.userLastName,
      ], null)
    }
  }`;
```

Then can I query corresponding view depending on dataset known.

So six complex key indexes instead of one. Quite heavy (in case of millions of records), but, unfortunately, the only possible solution.

Thanks to all responders, your help is unvaluable.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible with a single index. You can only do sub-key searches for the first part of the key.  To accommodate your needs, you'll need multiple indexes--and depending on how complex the queries you need to support, you may need a large number of indexes.

To support searching by first name, the index in your example is fine.

To support searching by last name, you could potentially reverse the index--or index *only* the last name.

If you need to search by middle name, you'll need a third index.  If you want to search by first and last names (omitting middle), you'll need yet another index, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can emit more than one index entry per document. To solve your simple example, you could create an index like this:

```
function(doc) {
    if (doc.userFirstName && doc.userLastName && doc.userGender && doc.homeCountry && doc.homeCity) {
      emit(doc.userFirstName, null);
      emit(doc.userMiddleName, null);
      emit(doc.userLastName, null);
    }
```

which would find "Mozart" through a simple search of the index. I suspect your actual requirement is more complex though - for example, the first or middle name might also be "Mozart" and therefore return a false positive if your search was specifically for Lastname="Mozart".

Comment: I thought this way but you are right - it means totally dismissing the value of complex key filtering, we just fall back to simple one - "find me if record contains this particular value anywhere"(
Now the only obvious solution seems to create views for all possible combinations of "known on entrance" values, like:    * * lastName => /view/_lastNameOnly, 
  fisrtName * lastName => /view/_firstLastName,  
etc.
 But it means a lot of indexes maintained which could be quite heavy in case of millions docs..

Comment: This makes it impossible to search for last name "John" independently from first name "John".

Answer (score 0):

A couchdb index has a single ordering; the key (the whole key) that you emit. This is obviously a very simple kind of index, but that makes it fast too.

One common method to address your problem is as follows;

```
function(doc) {
  if (doc.userFirstName) {
    emit(["firstname", doc.userFirstName], null);
  }
  if (doc.userMiddleName) {
    emit(["middlename", doc.userMiddleName], null);
  }
  if (doc.userLastName) {
    emit(["lastname", doc.userLastName], null);
  }
}
```

You can then query for any document where lastname = "Mozart" with ?key=["lastname", "Mozart"].

The advantage to this over a previous suggestion is you won't get false positives from documents where firstname or middlename is also Mozart.

Comment: But then what is your suggestion for query with i.e. given (known) firstname & lastname? This way you'll get all "Amadeus" records, then all "Mozart" records  - all of which you should combine/filter additionally, but not only those with "Amadeus" _and_ "Mozart" in there. I see no point, sorry

Comment: for a more complex query, you need a more complex index. There's couchdb-lucene which would allow AND queries (disclaimer: I wrote it) and there's the dreyfus/clouseau lucene integration for couchdb 2.0 (disclaimer: I also wrote that).

Comment: and I think the built-in query / mango thing can maybe handle that? Not something I'm very familiar with but the documentation explains what it can do.

Comment: Thank you for explanation. Full-text search is a bit overkill for my setup, but I decieded to implement "startsWidth" functionality - for partial name(s) search. So I ended with simple find query, which gives quite wide output (especially if name starts with beginning alphabet letters - a/A, b/B etc) and then just filter output programmaticaly. Not very perfect but working solution.